# Is the converse to total variation distance true?

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

For probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ define $d_{TV}(\mu,\nu)=\sup_{A}|\mu(A)-\nu(A)|$. This as we know is the total variation distance between $\mu$ and $\nu$.

I know that if $\mu_n$ is a sequence of probability measures and $X_n\sim\mu_n$, $X\sim\mu$ and $d_{TV}(\mu_n,\mu)\to 0$ then $X_n\to X$ weakly where $X_n, X$ take values on a countable set. This is because consider the set $(-\infty,x]$ for any $x\in\mathbb R$ then $|P(X_n\leq x)-P(X\leq x)|\leq \sup_A|\mu_n(A)-\mu(A)|\to 0$.

I am interested in the converse. Is it true that if $X_n\to X$ weakly, then $d_{TV}(\mu_n,\mu)\to0$?

I am thinking of the following:

Suppose $X_n\to X$ weakly. We further know that $$d_{TV}(\mu_n,\mu)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_j|\mu_n(\{j\})-\mu(\{j\})|$$

Now, using that $\min\{f_n,f\}=\dfrac{f_n+f-|f_n-f|}{2}$ i.e. $|f_n-f|=f_n+f-2\min\{f_n,f\}$, we have $d_{TV}(\mu_n,\mu)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_j[\mu_n(j)-\mu(j)-2\min\{\mu_n(j),\mu(j)\}]=1-\sum_j\min\{\mu_n(j),\mu(j)\}$.

Now $X_n\to X$ weakly implies that $\mu_n(j)\to\mu(j)$ for every $j$ in the **countable** set, and we also have that $\min\{\mu_n(j),\mu(j)\}\to\mu(j)$ implying by DCT, as $\min\{\mu_n(j),\mu(j)\}\leq \mu(j)$ and $\sum_j\mu(j)=1<\infty$, that $\sum_j\min\{\mu_n(j),\mu(j)\}\to\sum_j\mu(j)=1$ thereby showing that $d_{TV}(\mu_n,\mu)\to0$.

Is my argument right?

Comment: Your argument sounds correct.

Comment: 'the countable set' --> the countable set on which $X_n \to X$ weakly?